# Cannot restore Blackberry 10 signing key

Tags: code-signing, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-world

I have installed the Blackberry 10 signing key on my first laptop. Everything is okay here. Now I intend to move it to a new laptop. I copied the author.p12 and its db as mentioned in this tutorial:

[backup and restore blackberry 10 code signing key](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/backup_restore_signing_keys.html)

However, I still get this error message:

> Certificate chain not found for: RDK. RDK must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

No matter what I am doing, I am not be able to sign my applications on my new laptop. I also tried with both Win and Mac, but it does not help. I delete everything and re-install blackberry Webworks, but it does not help as well.

I searched on the internet, followed some tutorials but the issue is still the same. On blackberry site, it said:

[Error](https://developer.blackberry.com/air/documentation/cert_chain_not_found_2006079_11.html)

I am not sure what "Make sure that you correctly configured your computer for signing." means???

Can anybody help me, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the barsigner.csk and make sure you do not had two keys on your previous laptop. 
If still not working, install the Momentics IDE and use the GUI tool to backup the keys and restore it on your new laptop

Answer (score 0):

The 'Setup for Signing' docs on the Developer Micro Site should get you back on track.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup.html

It covers how to setup your computer for signing, as well as how to backup and restore your signing keys.

Comment: Actually, I followed exactly the structure of the link you provided. But it does not help. I will get the error message as mentioned above. Any other idea?